# Trying to figure out size of a linked list null pointer error

Tags: java, linked-list

For the below code, I would like to know why the size of the linked list keeps giving me a null pointer exeption and why my pushEnd method to push a new node at the end doesnt work, it add an element after a few nodes and gets rid of rest.

```
class Node {
int data;
Node next;
Node(int data){
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

```
public class LinkedList {
Node head;  

/* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
public Node push(int data) 
{ 
    Node newNode = new Node(data); 
    newNode.next = head; 
    return head = newNode; 
}

public Node pushEnd(int data) {
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
    }

    newNode.next = null;

    while(head != null) {
        head = head.next;
        head.next = newNode;
        return newNode;
        }
    return head;
}

public int getSize() {
    int size = 0;
    while(this.head != null) {
        size++;
        head = head.next;
    }
    return size;
}


public void printList() {
    while (this.head !=null) {
        System.out.print(head.data + "-->");
        head = head.next;
    }       
    System.out.println(head);
}
```

}

```
public class Tester {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList ll = new LinkedList();

    ll.push(35);
    ll.push(100);
    ll.push(14);
    ll.push(44);
    ll.push(10);
    ll.push(8);


    System.out.println("Created Linked list is:"); 
    ll.printList(); 



    System.out.println(ll.getSize());

}

}
```

I want to figure out the size of the linked list and be able to add nodes at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your `while` loops modify the `head` variable directly. This causes your other code to fail because now `head` is pointing to the last node in the list.

Create a new local variable for use in the while loops (instead of modifying head directly). That should fix it!

Answer (score 2):

You are changing `head` reference, due to which you are getting incorrect output. You should make `temp` refer to `head`, do your operation using `temp` which will not affect `head`. It should be like below:

```
public class LinkedList {
    Node head;

    /* Inserts a new Node at front of the list. */
    public void push(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        newNode.next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }

    public void pushEnd(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            return;
        }

        newNode.next = null;
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp.next != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = newNode;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        int size = 0;
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            size++;
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return size;
    }


    public void printList() {
        Node temp = this.head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.data + "-->");
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        System.out.println(temp);
    }
}

class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;

    Node(int data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome @madil26